# cannot import name 'mydb' from partially initialized module 'connection' in Python

Tags: python, importerror

Python 3.8 error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'mydb' from partially initialized module 'connection' 
(most likely due to a circular import) (C:\U
sers\Mark04\Documents\Python tutorial\databasing\connection.py)
```

When I tried to execute child module select.py

```
import bcrypt;
from connection import mydb
```

That has an imported module connection.py

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = "Success";
```

I don't know what is the problem. The error doesn't appear when I remove import mysql.connector from my module connection.py, but it does not solve my problem.

```
> python -m select
```

Comment: Could it be that you have another module (or script) named `mysql` in your `sys.path` that imports either `select` or `connection` ? In all cases, there's more to it than what you posted (I just tried your code example and it doesn't exhibit this issue), so please post a **proper** [mcve]

Answer (score 107, accepted):

To answer the above question, we need to understand the problem of circular dependency.

To understand the circular dependency, I want to layout a simple example, in front of you.

I think every app needs to have the few basic blocks as follows:

```
+----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    Filename    |                                        Description                                        |
+----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| app.py         | Creates the app and starts the server.                                                    |
| models.py      | Define what the entity will look like (e.g, UserModel has username, email, password etc.) |
| controllers.py | Fetches Data from database, generates HTML and sends the response to the user browser.    |
+----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Our simple example will also have three files

```
project/
    - app.py ( Creates and starts the server)
    - models.py ( Class to model a user)
    - controllers.py ( We will fetch data from database, and return html to user.)
```

The contents of the app.py file will look as follows:

```py
# =============
#     app.py
# =============

# Define the application
app = Flask()

# Define the Database
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# Register the Controller
from .controllers import auth_controller
app.register_blueprint(auth_controller)
```

The contents of the models.py file will look as follows:

```py
# =============
#     models.py
# =============

from .app import db

# We will not focus on implementation
class User(db.Model):
    pass
```

The contents of the controllers.py file will look as follows:

```py
# =============
#     controllers.py
# =============
from flask import Blueprint
from .models import User


# Create the auth app
auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)

# Define the Rotues
@auth.route('/login')
def login():
    return "I will fetch some data and allow the user to login"
```

I think now, I have laid out a diagram of our app, now let's proceed to understanding how the app will work.

1. The app starts from `app.py`
2. `app` variable inside the `app.py` file gets created in memory.
3. `db` variable inside the `app.py` gets created in memory.
4. Now, to import `auth` from `controllers.py` file we switch to ```controllers.py`` file
5. We import `Blueprint` from flask.
6. To import `User`, we switch to `models.py` file.
7. Now, inside `models.py` file we import `db` (We are able to import it because it was created in step 3)
8. And program continues so on and so on....

The most important import step in the above sequence is `step 7`, becuase it will cause the problem of circular dependency in our app, in just a moment.

Now we will try to change the `app.py` file to introduce the problem of circular dependency.

Now, as a developer, we might think that all our imports should be at the top of the file, doesn't it make your code cleaner. Yes, of course! it does make the code cleaner.

```py
# ============================
#       Refactored app.py file
# ============================
from .controllers import auth_controller

# ......
# Rest of the file is same, we only shifted this import at the top
```

Now, we have a problem of circular dependency in our app. Let me show you, how?

1. Our app starts from `app.py` file
2. First, we need to import `auth_controller` from `controllers.py` file
3. Let's visit the `controllers.py` file, and process it.
4. From flask we import Blueprint
5. Let's switch to `models.py` file to import `User`
6. Inside `models.py` file, we import `db` from `app` **(But db does not exist yet.)**

Now, I think you got the point, The problem if just saw, was an example of circular dependency. The same problem is causing the `ImportError` in your case.

The solution would be to inspect the `import statements` and put them at the right place. Sometimes, we use code formatter, and it refactors all the import statements at the top. This might be causing the problem for you.

I hope the this may answer your question!

Comment: I was following this example to get to the bottom of circular imports understanding and got circular error. My setup differences: 3 files dont have imports with dots `from .models import User` is `from models import User. and app has if __name__ == '__main__' entry at the bottom `app.run(debug=True)`. Between steps 7 and 8, after importing `db` to model, next line to be executed is `from controllers import auth_bp` which started the chain in the first place. Where is my blind spot?

Comment: __For Import Part:__ If you use imports without ., I think they are not going to make much difference, the problem will still exist, because of the order of instructions executed.

Comment: __For blind Spot__: I think you are missing the point that shifting the import at the top of the page caused the issue. The above example will still hold true in your case without dots in import.

Answer (score 47):

The order of the imports matters:

Example:

```py
# A.py
# empty file
```

```py
# B.py
import A
```

```
# file1.py
import A # A gets imported before B can import A
import B # B tries to re-import A but A is already imported
```

change the order to:

```py
# file1.py
import B
import A
```

Comment: This was the one that did it for me, the problem is not exactly a circular reference, but the module not being imported into a module before that module is imported and the reference to the first is called

Comment: I don't understand this example. This doesn't produce a problem in my environment and I don't see why this should produce import errors. Of course you can re-import modules that have already been imported earlier. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 24):

you can get rid of this error by not importing one of the conflicting imports at the top of the file. if you're only going to use what you're importing in a certain place, you can do your import within a function.

```
def foo():
    from x import y
```

Answer (score 10):

This error comes when you are attempting circular import. make sure you have not created any file with the same name with that of the module you are trying to import in the directory.

Answer (score 3):

The error says that it is "most likely due to a circular import".
Check to make sure that in the files you are importing you are not importing the file you showed. If you are that makes a circle of importing.
for example my file is file.py and I am importing file2.py:
import file > import file2 > import file > import file2 > import file...
Make sure that is not happening. I had the same problem as you and this fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I lowered the import instead of having all imports at the top.

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
from models import User
```

Answer (score 1):

A circular dependency issue, also known as circular reference or circular import, it occurs when two or more modules or components depend on each other in a way that creates a loop.

For Example:-

**Module A: a.py**

```
from b import foo_b

def foo_a():
    print("Foo A")
    foo_b()
```

**Module B: b.py**

```
from a import foo_a

def foo_b():
    print("Foo B")
    foo_a()
```

**SOLUTION:-**

**Refactor Code:** Split your code into smaller, more focused modules that have clear responsibilities. This reduces the likelihood of interdependent modules.

- ***Problem stated in above example can be solved by merging a.py & b.py in one file.***
- **Circular Dependency can also occur when we split our code into different file and import all of them in `__init__.py` file**, so arrange imports in such a manner that they don't conflict.

**`SADLY THERE'S NO AUTOMATED SOLUTION`**

Comment: agree. break them into smaller pieces

Answer (score -20):

I don't know the root cause, but it will work perfectly fine if you roll back to Python 3.7

Comment: Why do you think so?