# ImportError: cannot import name '...' from partially initialized module '...' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, django, importerror, python-module, circular-dependency

I'm upgrading an application from Django 1.11.25 (Python 2.6) to Django 3.1.3 (Python 3.8.5) and, when I run `manage.py makemigrations`, I receive this message:

```
File "/home/eduardo/projdevs/upgrade-intra/corporate/models/section.py", line 9, in <module>
    from authentication.models import get_sentinel**

ImportError: cannot import name 'get_sentinel' from partially initialized module 'authentication.models' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/eduardo/projdevs/upgrade-intra/authentication/models.py)**
```

My models are:

**authentication / models.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.utils import timezone

from corporate.constants import GROUP_SUPPORT
from corporate.models import Phone, Room, Section
from library.exceptions import ErrorMessage
from library.model import update_through_dict
from .constants import INTERNAL_USER, EXTERNAL_USER, SENTINEL_USERNAME, SPECIAL_USER, USER_TYPES_DICT


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        'User',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        unique=True,
        db_index=True
    )
    ...
    phone = models.ForeignKey('corporate.Phone', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, ...)
    room = models.ForeignKey('corporate.Room', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, ...)
    section = models.ForeignKey('corporate.Section', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, ...)
    objects = models.Manager()
    ...

class CustomUserManager(UserManager):

    def __init__(self, type=None):
        super(CustomUserManager, self).__init__()
        self.type = type

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(CustomUserManager, self).get_queryset()
        if self.type:
            qs = qs.filter(type=self.type).order_by('first_name', 'last_name')
        return qs

    def get_this_types(self, types):
        qs = super(CustomUserManager, self).get_queryset()
        qs = qs.filter(type__in=types).order_by('first_name', 'last_name')
        return qs

    def get_all_excluding(self, types):
        qs = super(CustomUserManager, self).get_queryset()
        qs = qs.filter(~models.Q(type__in=types)).order_by('first_name', 'last_name')
        return qs

class User(AbstractUser):
    type = models.PositiveIntegerField('...', default=SPECIAL_USER)
    username = models.CharField('...', max_length=256, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField('...', max_length=40, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField('...', max_length=80, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField('...', default=timezone.now)
    previous_login = models.DateTimeField('...', default=timezone.now)

    objects = CustomUserManager()
    ...
    def get_profile(self):
        if self.type == INTERNAL_USER:
            ...
        return None

    def get_or_create_profile(self):
        profile = self.get_profile()
        if not profile and self.type == INTERNAL_USER:
            ...
        return profile

    def update(self, changes):
        ...

class ExternalUserProxy(User):
    objects = CustomUserManager(type=EXTERNAL_USER)

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name = '...'
        verbose_name_plural = '...'

class InternalUserProxy(User):
    objects = CustomUserManager(type=INTERNAL_USER)

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name = '...'
        verbose_name_plural = '...'

def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created and instance.type == INTERNAL_USER:
        try:
            profile = UserProfile()
            profile.user = instance
            profile.save()
        except:
            pass

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)

def get_sentinel():
    try:
        sentinel = User.objects.get(username__exact=SENTINEL_USERNAME)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        settings.LOGGER.error("...")
        from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
        sentinel = User()
        sentinel.username = SENTINEL_USERNAME
        sentinel.first_name = "..."
        sentinel.last_name = "..."
        sentinel.set_unusable_password()
        sentinel.save()
        technical = Group.objects.get(name=GROUP_SUPPORT)
        sentinel = User.objects.get(username__exact=SENTINEL_USERNAME)
        sentinel.groups.add(technical)
        sentinel.save()
    return sentinel
```

**corporate / models / `__init__.py`**

```
...
from .section import Section
...
```

**corporate / models / section.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from authentication.models import get_sentinel
from .room import Room

class Section(models.Model):
    ...
    boss = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET(get_sentinel), ...)
    surrogate = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET(get_sentinel), ...)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, ...)
    is_subordinate_to = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, ...)
    ...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Update the question to show the imports at the top of `authentication/models.py`.

Comment: Now that you got your answer what you did wrong, here is some actual help: Use `from module import *` (in some cases).

Comment: This error might happen in case the name of your file is the same as the name of the package you connect. Just rename your file, and it will work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot import name 'mydb' from partially initialized module 'connection' in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59156895/cannot-import-name-mydb-from-partially-initialized-module-connection-in-pyth)

Comment: I didn't really understand what the problem was, so I used the other **models.py** the one where I imported models from and made the model there and it worked.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You have a circular import.

`authentication/models` imports `corporate/models`, which imports `corporate/models/section`, which imports `authentication/models`.

You can't do that.  Rewrite and/or rearrange your modules so that circular imports aren't needed.

One strategy to do this is to organize your modules into a hierarchy, and make sure that a module only imports other modules that are *lower* in the hierarchy.  (This hierarchy can be an actual directory structure, but it doesn't have to be; it can just be a mental note in the programmer's mind.)

Comment: I mean yeah. You can't do that. But some sense of how to address it could be useful.

Comment: just change the name of your file. Eg. you cant have ray.py and import ray as a package.

Comment: Can this be done?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72718121/6907424

Comment: See also [python - What can I do about "ImportError: Cannot import name X" or "AttributeError: ... (most likely due to a circular import)"? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/what-can-i-do-about-importerror-cannot-import-name-x-or-attributeerror) (which addresses a workaround using delayed import)

Comment: @John Gordon, please clarify what to do to fix it, instead of just repeating what the problem is and saying "you can't do that".

Comment: For future readers: if you're *only* importing a module for annotation purposes without actually using the content of the module, `from __future__ import annotations` tends to just *fix* stuff, also https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING

Answer (score 321):

For future readers, this can also happen if you name a python file the same name as a dependency your project uses.

For example:

I cannot have a file named retrying.py that is using the retrying package.

Assuming I had the retrying package in my project, I could not have a file called retrying.py with the below contents:

```
from retrying import retry
print("HI")
```

A similar error with the message "most likely due to a circular import" would occur.

The same contents would work fine if I renamed the file to "retrying_example1.py"

Comment: Remark: This answer addresses the question in [Python: is the current directory automatically included in path? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435697/python-is-the-current-directory-automatically-included-in-path). Future readers can see some explanation there.

Comment: exactly described my problem. amazing

Answer (score 13):

When importing code from other files, it helps if you spell out *the entire* subpackage where the thing you want to import comes from. Let's say you have the following file structure:

```
mypackage/
  subpackage/
    __init__.py
    helper.py
  main/
    work.py
```

If:

- `__init__.py` imports things from `helper.py` (for the end-user to conveniently access)
- and you're working inside `work.py`
- and you need something from `subpackage/helper.py`

Then rather than doing:

```py
from ..subpackage import thing_i_need
```

You should instead do:

```py
from ..subpackage.helper import thing_i_need
```

For reasonable code, this should help you avoid some of the circular dependency problems, as now you're no longer relying on `__init__.py` to fully finish.

Answer (score 6):

I received this error when I tried to do a relative import.  I had two models files:

`utils.models`:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    ...
```

`main.models`:

```
from .models import BaseModel
...
```

The problem was fixed when, in `main.models`, I changed it to:

```
from utils.models import BaseModel
```

Answer (score 5):

The order of imports in `__init__.py` matters:

**models/init.py**

```
from .a import A
from .b import B
```

**a.py**

```
from models.b import B

...
```

This will give `ImportError: cannot import name 'B' from partially initialized module 'models' (most likely due to a circular import) (/models/__init__.py)`

To resolve, the import of `B` should come before the import of `A` in `__init__.py`

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem was that I defined the function in the x.py file and in the x.py file I import models from the modals.py file and in the modals.py file I tried to import this function I was trying to set the default value after querying the tables with this function

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error below:

> AttributeError: partially initialized module 'math' has no attribute
> 'pi' (most likely due to a circular import)

Because I created **`math.py`**, imported **python's `math` module** in it and use **`math.pi`** in it as shown below:

```py
# "math.py"

import math

print(math.pi)
```

So, I changed **`math.py`** to **`my_math.py`**:

```py
# "my_math.py"

import math

print(math.pi)
```

Then, the error was solved:

```
3.141592653589793
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error.
I was doing this:( i.e. importing my `models` before blueprint object creation and model uses the `db` object defined in the `app.py` file. And this main_blueprint is getting registered in app.py.)

```
from ..models.user_model import User as user_model
main = Blueprint('main', __name__)
```

I fixed it by importing my model after blueprint object creation.

```
main = Blueprint('main', __name__)
# always import models after blueprint object creation.
from ..models.user_model import User as user_model
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this question shows up when googling the error message,

this might be helpful if you're using type hinting:

```
from __future__ import annotations # <-still need this.
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING: # <-try this,
    from my_module import MyClass # <-if this is only for type hinting.
```

It's very easy to get the circular import error `ImportError: cannot import name 'MyClass' from partially initialized module 'my_module' (most likely due to a circular import)` if we use type hints, because we import lots of classes. If type hinting is the problem, then the above solution will be helpful.

Note that we still need `from __future__ import annotations` even with Python 3.11 (as of 2023), according to the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.11.html#pep-563-may-not-be-the-future).

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will be helpful to future readers, I had this problem in Django because two models from different apps imported classes from eachother's model, a quick fix for me was to use dotted import.

Here is an example of what I mean by dotted import:
Given that we have two different apps, namely, **app_a** and **app_b**

**project/app_a/models.py**

```py
class ModelA(models.Mode):
    foo=models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**project/app_b/models.py**

```py
class ModelB(models.Model):
    bar=models.ForeignKey('app_a.ModelA', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to resolve circular imports is by splitting a file in the circle into multiple files in such a way that the files are no longer importing each other. In this specific case, I *think* it would be resolved if `get_sentinel` was moved to a separate file.

**authentication / models_utils.py**

```
def get_sentinel():
    ...
```

**corporate / models / section.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from authentication.models_utils import get_sentinel
from .room import Room

class Section(models.Model):
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I created two controllers `clients.py` and `users.py` that import from one another, causing **circular import**

```
from app.controllers.users import get_user_manager, UserManager

ImportError: cannot import name 'get_user_manager' from partially initialized module 'app.controllers.users' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Here is the exact scenario for clarification:

- The controller `client.py` imports `get_user_manager`, `UserManager` from `users.py` to use in its function `registerClient`
- Implemented `sendForgetPasswordMailClient` in `client.py` that does not use the import above
- In `users.py` I called `sendForgetPasswordMailClient` from `clients.py` that already imports from `users.py`, causing **circular import**

client.py

```py
...
from app.controllers.users import get_user_manager, UserManager


async def registerClient(
              client_password: ClientPasswordCreate, 
              client: UserCreate, 
              user_db: UserManager = Depends(get_user_manager), 
              db: Session = Depends(get_async_session)
              ):
   ...

async def sendForgetPasswordMailClient(client_mail, client_name, link):
   ...
```

users.py

```py
...
from app.controllers.clients import sendForgetPasswordMailClient

class UserManager(BaseUserManager[UserCreate, UserDB]):
    ...
    async def on_after_forgot_password(
        self, user: UserDB, token: str, request: Optional[Request] = None
    ):
        link = f'{APP_LINK}?token={token}'
        sendForgetPasswordMailClient(user.mail, user.firstName, link)

async def get_user_manager(user_db: SQLAlchemyUserDatabase = Depends(get_user_db)):
    yield UserManager(user_db)
```

The solution was simply to move `sendForgetPasswordMailClient` that does not contain any import from `users.py` to another file so I can call it freely from `users.py` without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

A circular import occurs when two or more modules depend on each other.
Faced this issue and was not sure where the problem was coming from. Took the new logic and added it to its own separate file and it worked because the modules were now separate and independent.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I was getting this error when I was trying to print statement inside of class when use streamlit.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and quick workaround solution, Instead of importing the models itself,import the whole file, for example instead of importing "get_sential" model from authentication.models in coprorate.models file import authentication itself and replace get_sential with authentication.models.get_sential

**corporate / models / section.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
import authentication
from .room import Room

class Section(models.Model):
    ...
    boss = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET(authentication.models.get_sential), ...)
    surrogate = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET(get_sentinel), ...)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, ...)
    is_subordinate_to = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to reference a model from another app, consider using a string reference.  This can help you avoid importing the model directly in modules that are part of the circular import.

```
service = models.ForeignKey('app1.Model2', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Answer (score -4):

yum install epel-release

dnf remove python3

dnf install  python3.11

Comment: Telling someone to replace their python install to fix a code issue is rather extreme.  Especially with no explanation