# IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable in implementin numerical scheme ODE solver

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numerical-methods, ode

In addition to my previous post [ODESolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72318064/importerror-cannot-import-name-ode-solver-odesolver-implementation-and-call-e/72327799#72327799) Ι try to implement antoher different numerical schemes. For example, I implement Runge-Kutta 4 order scheme for solver ODE class, and Forward Euler scheme. Basic superclass ODE_Solver code posted below:

```py
#ODS.py

import numpy as np


class ODE_Solver(object):
    """
    Supercalss sover ODE-s 
    Attribute:
    x: array of x coords
    u: solution array y(x)
    k: number of steps
    f: right hand side ODE equation: du/dx = f(u, x)
    """


    def __init__(self, f):
        if not callable(f):
            # check correct function f(u, x)
            raise TypeError('f is %s, not function' % type(f))
        self.f = lambda u, x: np.asarray(f(u, x), float)

    def solver_st(self):
        """Implement numerical scheme"""
        raise NotImplementedError

    def set_initial_condition(self, u0):
        if isinstance(u0, (float, int)):  # ODE 1-th order
            self.neq = 1
            u0 = float(u0)
        else:  # ODE high order or system of ODE-s
            u0 = np.asarray(u0)  # (initial conds)
            self.neq = u0.size
        self.u0 = u0

        # check correct lenght of vector f
        try:
            f0 = self.f(self.u0, 0)
        except IndexError:
            raise IndexError(
                'index out of bounds f(u,x). right index %s' % (str(range(self.neq))))
        if f0.size != self.neq:
            raise ValueError('f(u,x) return %d elems,  u has %d elems' % (f0.size, self.neq))

    def solve(self, coord_points, terminate=None):
        """
        Solve equations. Default False 
        """
        if terminate is None:
            terminate = lambda u, x, step_no: False

        if isinstance(coord_points, (float, int)):
            raise TypeError('solve: array lists not iterable')
        self.x = np.asarray(coord_points)
        if self.x.size <= 1:
            raise ValueError('ODESolver.solve requre coords x array')

        n = self.x.size
        if self.neq == 1:  # ODE
            self.u = np.zeros(n)
        else:  
            self.u = np.zeros((n, self.neq))

        # Assume self.x[0] corresponds to self.u0
        self.u[0] = self.u0

        # looping for x coords
        for k in range(n - 1):
            self.k = k
            self.u[k + 1] = self.solver_st()
            if terminate(self.u, self.x, self.k + 1):
                break  
        return self.u[:k + 2], self.x[:k + 2]
```

Forwar Euler scheme implement posted below:

```py
# ES.py

from abc import ABC
from ODS import ODE_Solver


class FE(ODE_Solver, ABC):
    """
    Attribute:
    x: array of x coords
    u: solution array y(x)
    k: number of steps
    f: right hand side ODE equation: du/dx = f(u, x)
    """

    def solver_st(self):
        u, f, k, x = self.u, self.f, self.k, self.x
        dx = x[k+1] - x[k]
        u_new = u[k] + dx*f(u[k], x[k])
        return u_new
```

If I call Forvard Euler scheme it is workin, but now I try to implement Adams-Bashfort-Moulton Scheme:

```py
#ADS.py

from abc import ABC
from ODS import ODE_Solver


class ABM4(ODE_Solver, ABC):
    """
    Attribute:
    x: array of x coords
    u: solution array y(x)
    k: number of steps
    f: right hand side ODE equation: du/dx = f(u, x)
    """

    def solver_st(self, alp=None):
        u, f, k, x = self.u, self.f, self.k, self.x

        for k in range(0,4):
            dx = x[k + 1] - x[k]
            dx2 = dx / 2.0
            K1 = dx * f(u[k], x[k])
            K2 = dx * f(u[k] + 0.5 * K1, x[k] + dx2)
            K3 = dx * f(u[k] + 0.5 * K2, x[k] + dx2)
            K4 = dx * f(u[k] + K3, x[k] + dx)
            u = u[k] + (1 / 6.0) * (K1 + 2 * K2 + 2 * K3 + K4)

        for k in range(4, self.x.size):
            dx = x[k + 1] - x[k]
            alp[k] = dx / 24 * (55 * f(u[k - 1], x[k - 1]) - 59 * f(u[k - 2], x[k - 2]) + 37 * f(u[k - 3], x[k - 3])
                                - 9 * f(u[k - 4], x[k - 4])) + u[k - 1]
            u_new = dx / 24 * (9 * f(u[k], alp[k]) + 19 * f(u[k - 1], x[k - 1]) - 5 * f(u[k - 2], x[k - 2])
                               + f(u[k - 3], x[k - 3])) + u[k - 1]
        return u_new
```

And if I try to call this solver (Adams-Bashfort-Moulton) method from another class in main file

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from tabulate import tabulate
from ADS import ABM4


def exact(x):
    return (np.exp(-3 * x) * (-129 * (x ** 4) - 16 * (x ** 3) + 54 * (x ** 2) + 36 * x)) / 12


def f(u, x):
    return (u[1],
            u[2],
            u[3],
            u[4],
            - 15 * u[4] - 90 * u[3] -
            270 * u[2] - 405 * u[1] - 243 * u[0])


y0 = [0, 3, -9, -8, 0]
solver = ABM4(f)
solver.set_initial_condition(y0)
x_points = np.linspace(0, 5, 50)
u, x = solver.solve(x_points)
y = u[:, 0]
plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', linewidth=3, markersize=3)
plt.plot(x, exact(x), 'r-')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

I get the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Fin_Proj_ODE\test1.py", line 29, in <module>
    u, x = solver.solve(x_points)
  File "C:\Fin_Proj_ODE\ODS.py", line 71, in solve
    self.u[k + 1] = self.solver_st()
  File "C:\Fin_Proj_ODE\ADS.py", line 22, in solver_st
    K1 = dx * f(u[k], x[k])
  File "C:\Fin_Proj_ODE\ODS.py", line 20, in <lambda>
    self.f = lambda u, x: np.asarray(f(u, x), float)
  File "C:\Fin_Proj_ODE\test1.py", line 17, in f
    return (u[1],
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**How to improve code and fix this bug?**

Probably, this bug tied with uncorrect loop implementation in `#ADS.py`, so the main loop iteration in ODE_Solver compute arrays of solution throughout the range `coord_points`. And so,now I don't understnd how to rewrite this loop in `ABM4` class.

Comment: Order of arguments. Decide if it is always `f(x,u)` or always `f(u,x)`.

Comment: @LutzLehmann

I use ordering arguments `f(u,x)`, and edit code for my post, but this troubleshoot not to fixed.

Comment: Still an argument error, but a new one, in `f(u[k], alp[k])`.

Comment: @LutzLehmann

I have should to use this args `alp[k]`, for implement numercial scheme, for correct and predict final solution value at `x[k]` point

Comment: Yes, and for that reason it should be `f(alp[k], x[k])` for the PECE scheme.