# Python ImportError: cannot import name '..' from partially initialized module '..' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python

I've read the other threads on this but they haven't really helped me.

I have to 2 .py files, both located under `ets.routes`, called `agreements.py` and `approvals.py`.
[image]

The file `agreements.py` imports several methods from `approvals`:

```
from ets.routes.approvals import getPendingApprovals, getIsApprover
```

It itself also exposes a utility method which should be available to `approvals` called `authorize_agreement`.

Now in `approvals.py` if I do

```
from ets.routes.agreements import authorize_agreement
```

I get the error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'getPendingApprovals' from partially initialized module 'ets.routes.approvals' (most likely due to a circular import) 
(C:\gitForVS\app\api\ets\routes\approvals.py)
```

I can't move `authorize_agreement` to some external file like `utils.py`, it really should be in `agreements.py` because it uses a lot of DB and associated Agreement-level code which is available there. It's just that this function should be imported by its sibling, while it itself imports some of the sibling's functions. Why is that such an issue? Are you required to have 1-way imports (e.g. from `approvals` -> `agreements` only) in Python?

Comment: This error usually means you have circular imports.

Comment: In fact, the code samples show this is a circular import.

Comment: You can make it a "conditional" import. If, for example, you only need `authorize_agreement` inside a specific function in the `approvals.py` module, put the import line inside that function. The import will then not be executed when the package or module is imported, but only by the time the function is executed, avoiding the circular import.

Comment: About your question "Are you required to have 1-way imports (e.g. from approvals -> agreements only) in Python?": think about what it means, when module A imports from module B, and module B imports form module A. You get a chicken and egg problem. Draw a few diagrams with your imports and see if you can solve it: you'll probably find you run into problems.

Comment: Not really, other languages allow it, like Java.

Answer (score 10):

The reason you're getting an error is because agreements.py can't import functions from approvals.py while approvals.py is simultaneously trying to import functions from agreements.py (hence the circular import error). One of your modules needs to define the functions the other wants before importing the functions it wants from the other.

For example:

File A:

```
from fileb import sum2

def sum(a, b):
    return a + b
```

File B:

```
def sum2(a, b):
    return a + b + a

from filea import sum # This works
```

Comment: Are there any corner cases? Or, a chance of getting an error due to race condition or anything?

Answer (score 2):

The reason I was encountering this error was technically explained by [the answer on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72718121) from @caleb-keller although not explicitly, but turned out to have a very simple explanation:

**The file name was the same as the library I was trying to import.**

My example: I created `elevenlabs.py` to ensure my API key was working and to try out some of the library functions.

The file started with `from elevenlabs import clone, generate [...]` but since the file itself was named `elevenlabs.py`, it tried to import from itself which of course won't work.