# ImportError: cannot import name 'math' from partially initialized module 'calculation'

Tags: python, module, calculation

I tried to import `calculation` in Python but I got the following error:

> ImportError
> cannot import name 'math' from partially initialized
> module 'calculation' (most likely due to a circular import)
> (/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/env_koki/lib/python3.10/site-packages/calculation/**init**.py)

Please, does anyone have any idea?

I need this module for the script:

```
result = calculation.calculate(x1, x2, op)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your modules have a circular import.  (module A imports module B, and module B imports module A.)  You can't do that.

Comment: Please see: [import error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64807163/importerror-cannot-import-name-from-partially-initialized-module-m)
You either have a circular import, or a module which is named the same with one of your packages
In case of circular import, you need to find 2 modules that causing this issue and fix your imports. If you have a bad naming, a simple refactoring will do

Comment: Thank you for your answers. However, I'm struggling to understand how I should change the imports. Because this module is built-in, which one should I rename it?