is there a solution for importing functions from files without happened a circular import?
iam making project on python and I make like 5 files + the mine.
one of these 5 files its shared files all the other files import from it functions.
but
the problem is that the shared file need to import from the other files a few functions too and that make the program Donte work when you run it.
I need a good solution for it
and thanks.
I tried to add another file to make the shared file import from it. but it doesn't work because its keep ask to defined things inside that new file.
i tried use inheritance by making classes in every file and it doesn't work too
for example:
file1.py
from file2 import new_root

def show_page1():
    for widget in root2.winfo_children():
    widget.destroy()

file2.py
def new_root():
   from file1 import show_page1
   global root2
   root2 = Tk()
   root2.title("MONEY")
   root2.geometry('1500x700')
   page1_label.bind("<Enter>", lambda e: page1_label.config(fg='dark blue'))
   page1_label.bind("<Leave>", lambda e: page1_label.config(fg='black'))
   page1_label.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: show_page1())


The solution is "reorganize your code so that circular imports aren't needed".

@JohnGordon can you give me an example?

You haven't shared your code, so it's hard to give an example that will help you.  Do you understand what a circular import is?

This past answer of mine https://stackoverflow.com/a/64809784/494134 might help.

@JohnGordon i edit my post chick the example code

from file1 import show_page1 Why is this statement in file2.py at all?  file2.py does not use the show_page1 function, so why import it?

@JohnGordon sry check it agene i update it i didn't tack all the code

Next question, why does file1 import new_root?  It isn't used.

The simplest solution (not the best, not the most performatic - but then you didn't post a minimal reproducible example of your modules so advise covering other cases can be made) -  is to move some of the import statements to inside  the functions.
file1.py
from file2 import function2

def function1():
   ...


file2.py
#move this import from here:
# from file1 import function1

def function2():
    #to here:
    from file1 import function1
    ...


i tride but it stiel give me error that the root2 is not defined and i import the thing that defined it for exam:
in file1.py
from file2 import new_root
def somthing():
for widget in root2.winfo_children():
widget.destroy()
and on file2.py
def new_root():
from file1 import somthing
global root2
root2 = Tk()
root2.title("MONEY")
root2.geometry('1500x700')

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

thanks
i wasn't know that this is the first post for me

i edit my post chick the example code

file1.py
def show_page1(root2):
    for widget in root2.winfo_cildren()
    widget.destroy()

file2.py
from file1 import show_page1

def neew_root():
    global root2
    root2 = Tk()
    root2.title("MONEY")
    root2.geometry('1500x700')
    page1_label.bind("<Enter>", lambda e: page1_label.config(fg='dark blue'))
    page1_label.bind("<Leave>", lambda e: page1_label.config(fg='black'))
    page1_label.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: show_page1(root2))

