# Using common constants module leads to circular import

Tags: python, importerror

I want to import constants from a `constants` module from two different modules, but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Temp\tmp\pycircular\pycircular\pycircular.py", line 2, in <module>
    from my_classes.foo import Foo
  File "C:\Temp\tmp\pycircular\pycircular\my_classes\foo.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pycircular.constants import ANOTHER_CONSTANT
  File "C:\Temp\tmp\pycircular\pycircular\pycircular.py", line 2, in <module>
    from my_classes.foo import Foo
ImportError: cannot import name 'Foo' from partially initialized module 'my_classes.foo' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Temp\tmp\pycircular\pycircular\my_classes\foo.py)
```

My project structure is the following:

```
  |-constants.py
  |-my_classes
  |  |-foo.py
  |  |-__init__.py
  |-pycircular.py
  |-__init__.py
```

```
# =============
#     pycircular.py
# =============

from constants import SOME_CONSTANT
from my_classes.foo import Foo


def main():
    print(SOME_CONSTANT)
    my_foo = Foo()
    my_foo.do_something()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
# =============
#     foo.py
# =============

from pycircular.constants import ANOTHER_CONSTANT


class Foo:

    def do_something(self):
        print(ANOTHER_CONSTANT)
```

```
# =============
#     constants.py
# =============

ANOTHER_CONSTANT = "ANOTHER"
SOME_CONSTANT = "CONSTANT"
```

I assume that it is the same problem as solved here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62303448/2021763.
But I really do not get why `from my_classes.foo import Foo` in `pycircular.py` is called a second time.

Update:

After renaming the package `pycircular` to `pycircular_pack` it worked in PyCharm.
But it only works because in Pycharm the option `Add content roots to to PYTHONPATH` is automatically set.

The output of `sys.path` is `['C:\\Temp\\tmp\\pycircular\\pycircular_pack', 'C:\\Temp\\tmp\\pycircular', 'C:\\Tools\\miniconda\\envs\\my_env\\python39.zip', 'C:\\Tools\\miniconda\\envs\\my_env\\DLLs', 'C:\\Tools\\miniconda\\envs\\my_env\\lib', 'C:\\Tools\\miniconda\\envs\\my_env', 'C:\\Tools\\miniconda\\envs\\my_env\\lib\\site-packages']`

Without the option the output is `['C:\\Temp\\tmp\\pycircular\\pycircular_pack', 'C:\\Tools\\miniconda\\envs\\my_env\\python39.zip', 'C:\\Tools\\miniconda\\envs\\my_env\\DLLs', 'C:\\Tools\\miniconda\\envs\\my_env\\lib', 'C:\\Tools\\miniconda\\envs\\my_env', 'C:\\Tools\\miniconda\\envs\\my_env\\lib\\site-packages']`

And without the option I only get it to work with absolute imports.

```
# pycircular.py

from constants import SOME_CONSTANT
from my_classes.foo import Foo

...
```

```
# foo.py

from constants import ANOTHER_CONSTANT
```

Comment: If everything here is under a `pycircular/` package, and you're able to import `my_classes` like that, your Python import path is incorrect (i.e. it includes the `pycircular` directory as a root). You will want to fix that first, because it will lead to all sorts of confusion down the road. You should only be able to import those modules in the package as `from pycircular.constants import ...` or `from .constants import ...`, not with absolute imports.

Comment: Thank you. I simply renamed the package and it worked, without other changes.

Comment: That still means there's something weird about your `sys.path`. Do try `import sys; print(sys.path)`...

Comment: I updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate based on the comments and edit:

> After renaming the package pycircular to pycircular_pack it worked in PyCharm. But it only works because in Pycharm the option Add content roots to to PYTHONPATH is automatically set.

You should make sure the package directory is **not** set as a content root or source root. The directory hosting the package directory should be set as source root.

```
C:\Temp\tmp\pycircular  # <- source root
|- pycircular_pack  # <- not set as anything
|  |- constants.py
|  |- my_classes
|  |  |- foo.py
|  |  |- __init__.py
|  |- pycircular.py
|  |- __init__.py
|- other_file.py  # <- for illustration's sake
```

Now your `sys.path` will be set to include `C:\Temp\tmp\pycircular` only and there will be exactly one way to import things from your module.

Namely,

- `other_file.py` (outside the package) will be able to use the package as `pycircular_pack`
- `pycircular_pack/*.py` can refer to modules in the `pycircular_pack` package by either

  - (e.g.) `from .constants import ...` (relative import from current package), or
  - (e.g.) `from pycircular_pack.constants import ...` (absolute import)
- `pycircular_pack/my_classes/*.py` can refer to modules in the `pycircular_pack` package by either

  - (e.g.) `from ..constants import ...` (relative import from parent package), or
  - (e.g.) `from pycircular_pack.constants import ...` (absolute import)

If your `pycircular_pack` package would contain a runnable script, e.g. a CLI as `pycircular_pack/cli.py`, then the correct way to run that script on the command line would be to use `python -m pycircular_pack.cli`; this has Python set up the path just like we want here, where `python pycircular_pack/cli.py` would not do the right thing.